# Is there any way use new DrawerLayout with ActionBarSharlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am wondering if there any way to use new DrawerLayout from support library with ActionBarSherlock?
I found workaround for ICS+ but what i need is support for android 2.2+
The problem is that ABS hold reference for original android.view.MenuItem only when ICS+ but for older version there is inner implementation that not hold reference for original one.

Comment: I was able to implement it without any trouble. If you're having an issue we can't help if we dont know what it is.

Comment: Did you implement it with ActionBarSherlock? How you deal with fact that new DrawerLayout require `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` in `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` when **MenuItem** is of type `android.view.MenuItem`? When you extend `SherlockActivity` you will get MenuItem of type `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`

Comment: that's different, I didn't implement a drawer toggle. however the Drawer does work with ActionBarSherlock, to what extent I'm not sure, I recommend creating a new question with what you just asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a project on GitHub that works perfectly

[SherlockNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/tobykurien/SherlockNavigationDrawer)

Hope this helps

Comment: For the curious, what this example does is basically wrap the sherlock MenuItem class with the standard Android MenuItem class so that the usual DrawerLayout.onOptionsItemSelected() method may be used.

Comment: Is drawer icon supported by that workaround? I finally turned out to migrate with AppCompat for other reasons but its good to know.

Answer (score 22):

If you are looking a way to open and close the DrawerLayout when user touch Icon from ActionBar, you can use this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @justin.harrison Great! Good to know that!